# If I run ./configure, then make again, then will it ruin things if I want to run make a 2nd time?

Tags: make

http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/netcdf-install/Quick-Instructions.html#Quick-Instructions

is what I'm trying to install. Anyways, I ran ./configure and make but then I ran make without "make check install". So I'm thinking of running make with "make check install". Is the possibility of this ruined now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run `make help` and you will see, what does each target effectively do. Or read the `Makefile`.

In general, you should run `make clean` before recompilation to ensure you build the program the way you have configured it. Depending on the `Makefile`, targets may not be re-compiled if the products of compilation/linking is already found. A sane `Makefile` should include checks which determine if recompilation is needed. But if you want to be on the safe side, just run `make clean`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to rebuild an executable in order to check it and install it, so just `make check install` should be fine.
However, in case you need to rebuild the executables, such as to add functionality, just remaking `make` won't work.  Because `make` sees the old executable and assumes noting needs to be done.  so you should run `make clean` before, or `make distclean` in some cases.

Comment: It's related to the Makefile, usually, the excutable depends on other files (at least, the source file). `make` rebuilds it if any of its dependencies change.

Comment: I was talking about changing `./configure` options.